# samba network share fails to mount at boot time

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs, systemd-networkd, apparmor

On a box with Ubuntu 20.04, I struggle to mount a network share at boot time. Manually mounting the same share with `sudo mount /media/SHARE` works without any issues, and the same `/etc/fstab` entries work on other but much slower machines.

Here is my `/etc/fstab` entry:

```
//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/SHARE   /media/SHARE cifs uid=xxx,gid=xxx,_netdev,x-systemd.after=network-online.target,credentials=xxx,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770,iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0,noperm 0 0
```

Here is what I see in dmesg:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i cifs
[    9.934798] FS-Cache: Netfs 'cifs' registered for caching
[    9.939119] Key type cifs.spnego registered
[    9.939122] Key type cifs.idmap registered
[    9.939255] CIFS: Attempting to mount //xx.xx.xx.xx/SHARE
[    9.939292] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    9.939296] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
[  545.462599] CIFS: Attempting to mount //xx.xx.xx.xx/SHARE     <-- works, manually invoked
```

Inspecting the boot process with `systemd-analyze plot`, I see
`NetworkManager.wait-online.service (6s)` and then `network-online.target` reached after approx 9.85 seconds. It thus seems to me that the option to wait in `/etc/fstab` does what it should.

What may be the reason for this to fail?

Should I wait for another target? Which would that be?

Is there a possibility to add, as a hack, a fixed further delay of e.g. 1 second just to check whether this works?

Comment: Please try using `noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=10` instead of `_netdev,x-systemd.after=network-online.target`. It will not mount it on boot but it will mount it as soon as you attempt to use it.

Comment: If possible, I would like to avoid automount. And I am interested why the above fails.